# How to retrieve/recover commands that I ran on windows command prompt before the last restart?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I was debugging an issue via command prompt and was trying many scripts/commands and somehow one of them worked. So in excitement, I restarted my machine.

Now I don't really remember which command did actually worked for me. How do I recover all the commands that I ran before the restart? Is there any way to find out that in Windows 10?

Comment: Related: [Is there a global, persistent CMD history?](https://serverfault.com/questions/95404/is-there-a-global-persistent-cmd-history)

Comment: ok, I misunderstood your question. You want the commands that you run in the last session before a reboot. use clink, it keeps history of all files. this is the correct answer, as written in the duplicate link.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Windows cmd doesn't have an option to save the command history to a file, that can be used across sessions, like bash or other unix shells do.

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's partially correct. Cmd history does not persist across restarts so "You can't" is a correct answer to the OPs actual question.

Comment: Updated the answer to expand and clarify saving the command history.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 3):

It depends if it was just a Command Prompt window or actually a PowerShell window. If it was PowerShell and you are running version 5 (latest) then you are in luck. Just press the Up button in the prompt.

Alternatively, if this isn't the case, then for future reference you could have a look at this post about saving history:

[PowerShell v5 includes command history](http://woshub.com/powershell-commands-history/)

Essentially PS5 implements what used to be a third party add-on. So if you aren't running PS5 you can still install it so this doesn't happen to you again.

Answer (score 2):

What is essential in your question is that you want to see what you typed **AFTER you restarted the computer**.

Thus, there is no logging for commands launched in a CMD prompt.

On the other hand, there are PowerShell​ logs, but you must have configured them before.